# Why does this void method empty the deck?

Tags: java, arraylist

Following is a method that takes an ArrayList of Card objects, deck, as an argument, sets up a second ArrayList, shuffled, capable of holding Card objects, and then randomly picks Cards out of deck one by one, adding them to the second ArrayList. Once the deck is empty, the deck variable is assigned a reference to the newly-filled ArrayList, which is shuffled. For some reason though, when I send this method a non-empty ArrayList argument, it completely empties out the deck. Why is this?

```
public static void shuffle(ArrayList<Card> deck)
{
    Random randy = new Random();
    ArrayList<Card> shuffled = new ArrayList<Card>();

    while (!deck.isEmpty())
    {
        int c = randy.nextInt(deck.size());
        shuffled.add(deck.remove(c));
    }

    deck = shuffled;
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm guessing that your `Deck.remove` function is most likely `void`, and removes a `Card` object from the `ArrayList`. Check if the `remove` function actually returns a `Card` object.

Comment: @voidHead No, the `ArrayList.remove()` method returns a reference to the object removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an example of how call by value is implemented in java . When you do the below example , your original deck is being altered

```
 shuffled.add(deck.remove(c));
 // Changes the value of the underlying object of deck reference, hence
 // both the original deck and the deck variable in the function are altered
```

The below statement only changes the reference of the variable in the function. Your original deck object still is an emptied out list

```
deck = shuffled;
// The deck variable in the function  is now  pointing to shuffled within
// the function. This deck variable is lost after your function call ends.
```

Comment: So when I pass an ArrayList<Card> to shuffle, it doesn't actually use the exact ArrayList I sent it, but instead creates an identical ArrayList to work with?

Comment: No. It assigns the memory address of the ArrayList passed in to the local identified `deck`. The only thing being created is the ArrayList initially assigned to `shuffle`.

Comment: *How* is this related to the Evaluation Strategy of "Call by Value"? (If anything it merely has to do with the incorrect assumption that a copy/clone/duplicate of objects passed as an argument is made.)

Answer (score 4):

`deck` is a local identifier which is assigned the heap location of the ArrayList which is passed in. When `shuffled` is declared it is assigned a different heap location. Assigning `deck` to `shuffled` does not change the original ArrayList as it is declared in the heap.

Use [Collections.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-) and save yourself some trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As described in another answer, you have emptied the original arraylist, but haven't put anything back into it as you have changed the local reference only. The following code adds the shuffled items back into the original deck arraylist.

```
public static void shuffle(ArrayList<Card> deck)
{
    Random randy = new Random();
    ArrayList<Card> shuffled = new ArrayList<Card>();

    while (!deck.isEmpty())
    {
        int c = randy.nextInt(deck.size());
        shuffled.add(deck.remove(c));
    }

    // this line will copy the shuffled items back into the deck array
    deck.addAll(shuffled);

}
```

Comment: While technically correct, I feel it is erroneous to suggest a sub-optimal solution when another answer already explains the specific problem.

Comment: Biswajit_86 has explained the problem, but not provided a solution. And you answered after I did.

Comment: I was referring to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23600171/122207 ... which you referenced.

Comment: Yes. It explained the problem but didn't offer a solution. In any case, your solution is better than mine.

Comment: You're right, all of the answers were incomplete, but SO rules prevent me from changing my vote.